# find -regex not recognizing what seems like a good query

Tags: regex, find, posix

Using egrep, the regular expression "^.{8}$" matches any filename of exactly 8 characters:

```
jeff@jbb-lenovo:~/smsn+/kb/vcs/private$ ls | egrep "^.{8}$"
ac7t6-Xo
aQsqsC4-
a_wzemGk
jeff@jbb-lenovo:~/smsn+/kb/vcs/private$
```

But using find, whether I use posix-extended or the ordinary kind, that pattern does not work:

```
jeff@jbb-lenovo:~/smsn+/kb/vcs/private$ find . -regex "^.{8}$"
jeff@jbb-lenovo:~/smsn+/kb/vcs/private$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.{8}$"
jeff@jbb-lenovo:~/smsn+/kb/vcs/private$
```

In fact I tried all the other regextypes -- emacs, posix-basic, posix-awk, posix-egrep -- as listed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html).

Comment: Why not just `ls ????????`?

Comment: I didn't know `ls` supported wildcards. Thanks!

Comment: Wildcards are expanded by the shell, so every command supports them automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because output of `find` will also include `./` before each filename since your path argument is `.`

You can use:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "^[^/]{10}$"
```

Or else:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "^\./[^/]{8}$"
```

use of `[^/]` instead of `.` ensures we don't match filenames in subdirectories.

Or we could use `-maxdepth 1` as well to avoid matched in subdirectories:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex "^\./.{8}"
```

Comment: Note that this will match filenames in subdirectories, if the combined length is 8, e.g. `./foo/1234`

Comment: Yes that's right since `.` matches `/` as well. OP may use: `[^/]{8}` instead of `.{8}`